# How to create a pdf file using react-pdf and your own component without using react-pdf components?

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

I have my own component that uses andt I want to select some object in a table and pass it to my component and download it as a pdf.

I tried wrapping my component but nothing happened just my text was gone

```
const DocumentForPrint = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Document>
    <Page size="A4">
        { children }
    </Page>
  </Document>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can wrap you own React component with the react-pdf library. You have to use to given components like  or . Depending on your {{ children }} content you have 2 solutions :

- Change the way you send props to your `DocumentForPrint` function and work with existing components like View, Text, Image etc.
- There is a [react-pdf-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-html) package which add an  component for this PDF generation. This will allow you to use html/css. You should be able to wrap any content using this one